# Both C and D drives behave as non-persistent, even though i have set C drive as "non-persistent" and D drive as "Persistent"

Tags: virtual-machines, hard-drive, vmware-vsphere, terraform

Is it the disk, which behaves as persistent and non persistent or the VM?

I have a **VM on my vsphere with two disk drives ( C and D )**, Both Drives are marked as **THIN PROVISIONED**. this machine is being used as a CI/CV node. C drive has the OS installed on it and D drive has jenkins and gitcode.

i want to make **c drive as non persistent** , so that the changes happening to this drive does not stick in my VM after i restart the machine. at the same time i want my **D drive to be Persistent**, so that the logs and other screenshots taken should remain in the D drive.

I made the c drive as non persistent and D drive as persistent disk in Vsphere VM edit option But when i use this machine now.. **Both C drive as well as D drive behave as NON Persistent**, Datafiles created during execution are getting deleted from D drive as well.

#### Drive D

[image: Drive D]

#### Drive C

[image: Drive C]

Comment: Please provide the configuration of your virtual disks, as screenshots if necessary.

Comment: uploaded screenshots..

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly unusual use-case for this but yes it can be done.

Just set the underlying disk for your C: drive to be 'Independent Non-Persistent Mode' and the underlying disk for your D: drive to be Persistent and I think you'll get what you want. Good luck.

Comment: I have already done that, made C drive as independent -non persistent and D drive as independent - persistent, but still the files which were added to D drive(persistent drive), are getting deleted from D drive after switching VM OFF and ON.  C drive is behaving as expected.

Comment: ah! are they on separate disk controllers?! If I recall correctly they have to be, sorry should have mentioned that before.

Comment: MY VMs have (LSI Logic SAS) controller. There was only one controller earlier - "SCSI controller 0".   I added one more controller: "SCSI controller 1" based on your comment. now my two drives are on different controllers....... i am still facing the same issue. D drive is still behaving as non-persistent. Data is getting deleted from there.

Comment: That's odd, I know you need separate controllers but that should have fixed it, sorry

Comment: its working now. Strangely on the first go it failed...but now when i retried, its working properly. Thanks alot for your help :)

Comment: Oh more than happy to help - normally I'd have said it was the result of a reboot but you must have shut down the VM to add the second controller and disk - so it can't be that - just glad you're sorted anyway.